# MySQL load data infile error with enclosed

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a MySQL to load data from csv to table.

```
load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/data.csv'
into table tb_booking
ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 ROWS
(id,booking_no,mso_id,po_id,po_ref_no,marks_and_no,goods_desc);
```

But I am encountering error saying (**ENCLOSED is not a valid input at this position**). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As error states, your position of `Enclosed` by is not correct. Your command should be like below.

```
load data infile 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/data.csv'   into table tb_booking(id,booking_no,mso_id,po_id,po_ref_no,marks_and_no,goods_desc)  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: what separator you have used for terminating your fields? I assumed it to  be comma(,).